# How to find what element mouse is over in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a situation where an element is shown using ajax.  I have attached mouseenter and mouseleave events to it to show a menu connected to the element using prototype.  This works fine, but the problem I am having is that if a user has his/her mouse in the place where the element is shown before it is shown, the mouseenter does not get triggered and the attached menu does not get shown.  I already have an afterFinish function that is called after a SlideDown effect, so I was thinking I could put another function in there to check if the users mouse is over the element or not.  How would I go about checking what element the users mouse is over in prototype?

Answer (score 0):

Give the focus to another element of the page. That will trigger your event.

Comment: I think that would work for a mouseover event, but what about a mouseenter?